# bootrap modal showed after the loop

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I want my bootstrap modal shown before the For-Loop function but the code below displayed the modal after the loop.

```
var total = 5000;

$('#loading2').show().modal();

for (start = 1; start <= total; start++) {
        console.log(start);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var total = 5000;
        
$('#loading2').show().modal();
        
$('#loading2').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  for (start = 1; start <= total; start++) {
      console.log(start);
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi @Pakawat, still not working. the modal displayed after loop is finished

Comment: Probably your modal is take too much time to show, You can try to do async/await by create function of show modal.